# Is Webworker necessary in my case ? Websocket returns array of over 50,000 elements to be rendered in React

Tags: reactjs, websocket, web-worker

Question, is webworker for websocket needed in my case?

Currently, I have a custom React hook that creates a websocket instance, this websocket
will continuously fetch over 50,000 elements which is then rendered as rows on the user interface.

During loading, the user doesn't actually need to click around, as it's just a search page. There is the possibility to click on a row while loading, which opens a panel of "more info" regarding that row. But in general, the user doesn't need to do other tasks while waiting for all data to load (can take 2-3 minutes)

I don't want to start coding a webworker for this if there is no end benefit to the user or to the efficiency of the application.

Would a webworker:

- make the data load faster? probably not
- Will it make rendering the frontend more efficient? I don't THINK so, correct me if I'm wrong.

It seems its only good if the user needs to do OTHER things while the data is loading.

Also, I do have a 5 second set-interval polling to get data. For the rest of the react application which updates a context. Perhaps THAT can be moved to a webworker?

Would love any insight on whether not a webworker would be helpful

Comment: You're asking the wrong questions. The question you should be asking yourself is: do I *really* need to be processing 50,000+ data objects in the front-end?

Comment: (and also, no, a web worker is useless here because your bottleneck is updating the DOM, which a web worker doesn't have access to)

Comment: Since the API doesnt have pagination, is it possible to say, store the 50,000k object in a webworker, and make the frontend query and render 200 at a time or something? Anyway thanks for the input! Seems like I won't be implementing it.